# Cout doesn't generate anything (Polynom Interpolation)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int const max=400;
    char name_holder [max];
    double x_values [max];
    double f_x_values [max];
    
    cout << "Polynome Interpolation"<<endl;
    cout << "Name of the data file: ";
    cin >> name_holder;
    
    //How to read datas from the data file:
    
    ifstream data_file_c (name_holder);
    
    if(!data_file_c)
    {
        cout << "Something went wrong!"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int size_count=0;
    
    while (data_file_c >> x_values[size_count] >> f_x_values[size_count])
    
    {
        cout << "Punkt (x,f(x)) " << x_values[size_count] << " " << f_x_values[size_count] << endl;
        size_count++;
    }
    
    data_file_c.close();
    
    cout << "Nr. of points: " << size_count <<endl;
    
    ofstream newd ("given_points.dat");
    
    if(!newd)
    
    {
        cout << "Error of new data file!" <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(true)
    {
        double t;
        double k=0;
        double tmp=1;
        cout <<"Give a new point: ";
        cin >> t;
        
        if(0==t)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<size_count;i++)
        {
            double rropt = f_x_values[i];
            for(int j=0;i<size_count;j++)
            {
                if(j!=i)
                {
                    rropt *= ((t - x_values[j])/(x_values[i] - x_values[j]));
                }
                
            }
            k += rropt;
        }
        cout << "New data point (x,f(x)): " << t << " " << k << endl;
        newd << t << " " << k <<endl;
    
    }

    newd.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote the above code about Polynomial interpolation. I think the syntax and the logic is correct. The problem is that when I give an x value for which I want the f(x) value, the code doesn't return anything back. It would have been Ok if I would have been better to have a wrong value than no value at all. What is the problem? The focus should be in the double for loops

Comment: So you do not even get "Polynome Interpolation"? It is the part which you do flush explicitly, early and unconditionally.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], ideally one which does not need input (i.e. use hardcoded init values instead). Make sure you also provide the expected output and the output you get in comparison.

Comment: The only problem is by the 2 for loops, when I do cout << ... nothing is displayed in the screen

Answer (score 2):

You get into an infinite loop here:

```
for(int j=0;i<size_count;j++)
```

You are incrementing `j`, but use `i` in condition `i<size_count`

Comment: Thank you! That was it. A typo made me waste 30 min

Comment: @imbAF some people waste way more than that on a typo :) I blame a `copy/paste` design patern :)

Comment: You should get access to a debugger. With Visual Studio or gdb you should have seen the issue in less than 5 minutes. If you debugged inside the loop.

Comment: @VladFeinstein guilty of that :D

Comment: @drescherjm thx for the info, will def. check that

Comment: Single-letter variable names... They the devil, man.